# A good web font size for Chinese characters

Tags: fonts

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_language) has a pretty small font size for Chinese characters like 書. I would prefer if it were a little larger. Wondering if there is a sort of reference or ideal size for Chinese characters, similar to how a good estimate/range for Latin-based fonts is around 14-16px.

Comment: px is a device-dependent unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among others, [Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5) has a font of 15px, [Yahoo News](https://tw.news.yahoo.com) has a font of 18 px, and the font of [Sina News](https://news.sina.com.cn) is also 18 px.